# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when inserting subview? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, exc-bad-access

When i use the method `insertSubview:atIndex:` on my iPhone the program fails to run, with EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the main.m file. However, when i use `presentModalViewController` the program runs perfectly.

Also, the method switchToView works when its first used, with a different to and from, but the second time it doesn't.

What is going wrong?

Here is my code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{    
  ShowBookDetails *sbd = [[ShowBookDetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShowBookDetails" bundle:nil];
  [self switchToView:sbd from:self];
}
```

My method look like:

```
-(void)switchToView:(UIViewController*)nextView from:(UIViewController*)currentView
{
  [currentView.view insertSubview:nextView.view atIndex:1];
}
```

Comment: Most likely though, it sounds like you are trying to insert a viewController using the insertSubview.  A viewController is not a view, and cannot be inserted this way!!!

Comment: Code has been posted, and i've used nextView.view, so it shouldn't be because of that, but thanks!

Comment: You realize though, that what you are trying to do STILL, is to make a view a subview of two different view controllers! Im not sure this is possible!  Further, why dont you want to use presentModalViewController?

Comment: Exact, you have to switch the view controller, or push it programmatically.

Comment: @trumpetlicks when a view is added as a subview of another view, it get removed from its original view

Comment: So it is not possible to add a subview to something thats already been made a subview of something else?

Comment: Very sorry, forgot to mention that the method switchToView works when its first used, with a different to and from, but the second time it doesn't.

Comment: Read my newest answer, read the UIViewController documentation for the view property!!!

Comment: have you tried the method by removing the "atIndex:1". use just [currentView.view addSubview:nextView.view];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look here at the view property

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

It stricly states exactly what I stated in a comment:

"Each view controller object is the sole owner of its view. You must not associate the same view object with multiple view controller objects. The only exception to this rule is that a container view controller implementation may add this view as a subview in its own view hierarchy. Before adding the subview, the container must first call its addChildViewController: method to create a parent-child relationship between the two view controller objects."

Straight from Apple!

Comment: No he's right.  You're setting up a view structure that's not in sync with the ViewController structure.  You either need to create a proper Container View Controller or use one Apple provides, like a UINavigationController.

Comment: Thank you very much!
Just to clarify, i added `[currentView addChildViewController:nextView];` to the method

Comment: It seems like people are always grabbing a view of another view controller and trying to transition to it! By the way, [WWDC 2011 session 102](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102), which is about view controller containment, has a lengthy discussion about the importance of keeping view controller hierarchies synchronized with view hierarchies.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {    
ShowBookDetails *sbd = [[ShowBookDetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShowBookDetails" bundle:nil];

[self switchToView:sbd from:self.view];
}

-(void)switchToView:(UIViewController*)nextView from:(UIView*)currentView{
[currentView insertSubview:nextView.view atIndex:1];
}
```

Modify to this code

Comment: How is this different than what he has?  He is already using currentView.view in his code, all this has done is changed when he gets currentView.view, but functionally nothing different!

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem:

```
ShowBookDetails *sbd = [[ShowBookDetails alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShowBookDetails" bundle:nil];
```

If you're not using ARC it's a memory leak because you have no way to release the object once the method containing that line ends.

If you **are** using ARC, it will automatically release `sbd` and anything in its view that refers to the controller will be trying to use a dealloc'd object.

You should make `ShowBookDetails *sbd` a strong (or retain) property in this class rather than a local variable.